# Nesting list in model and the viewing and storing data

Tags: c#, asp.net

Sorry if this is a simple question but if I want to have a list inside a model, and later access and set the values of the list?

Say my main model looks like this:

```
public class StartPageModel : IPageViewModel<StartPage>
{
    public IList<ListContent> ListContent { get; set; }
    public StartPage CurrentPage { get; set; }
}

public class ListContent
{
    public IList<ListElement> ArticleListContent { get; set; }
    public IList<ListElement> InsightListContent { get; set; }
}
```

How can I set the ArticleListContent list to a value by referencing the parent model?

```
public ActionResult Index(StartPage currentPage)

{
var model = new StartPageModel(currentPage);    
model.ListContent.ArticleListContent = GetListContent(currentPage.ArticleCollection);
}
```

However this returns the error:

> IList does not contain a definition for 'ArticleListContent'

Comment: @Frost what is that supposed to mean? This is a compilation error, using a different browser isn't going to change anything.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you require a collection of `ListContent` in your `StartPageModel`, correct me if I'm wrong.

Change

```
public IList<ListContent> ListContent { get; set; }
```

to

```
public ListContent ListContent { get; set; }
```

And provided `ListContent` is initialized, your assignment will work.

Answer (score 1):

It's because it's referencing the List of ListContent, not an individual item in that list. Here's some examples:

```
        var model = new StartPageModel(currentPage);

        model.ListContent[0].ArticleListContent = GetListContent(currentPage.ArticleCollection); // Access first in list
        model.ListContent[1].ArticleListContent = GetListContent(currentPage.ArticleCollection); // Access secondin list
        model.ListContent.First().ArticleListContent = GetListContent(currentPage.ArticleCollection); // Access first in list using Linq
```